# Deploy Spark Java on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to deploy SparkJava on tomcat. In web.xml I have

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>spark.servlet.SparkFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>RestCheckerService</param-name>
            <param-value>rest.RestCheckerService</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And when I'm trying to deploy Spark I have this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at spark.servlet.SparkFilter.getApplication(SparkFilter.java:92)
    at spark.servlet.SparkFilter.init(SparkFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279) 
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at spark.servlet.SparkFilter.getApplication(SparkFilter.java:89)
```

My Filter Class

```
public class RestCheckerService implements SparkApplication{
  ...

    @Override
    public void init() {
      ...

        Spark.get("/scheme/:groupName/:schemeName/:version", new Route() {
            @Override
            public Object handle(Request request, Response response) {
                try {
return gson.toJson(clientDB.getScheme(request.params(":groupName"), request.params(":schemeName"), Integer.parseInt(request.params(":version"))));

                } catch (DaoException e) {
                    return RestErrorCodes.ERROR;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Maybe it happened because I used Java7 not Java8

Comment: Can you show us the content inside SparkFilter class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
<param-name>RestCheckerService</param-name>
```

with

```
<param-name>applicationClass</param-name>
```